# how to Edit/update Data Via Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, datagridview, asmx

I have a C# asmx webservice.  I am using a DataGridView to retrieve the data and that works well.  But I also would like to select a record and update the data. And editing the data. Then create a button event that sends the data back to the web service so the database can be updated. Do you guys have any suggestions or sample code i might be able to look at as an example? i doing all this code in visual studio

Thank you very much for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to bind with the OnRowUpdating and call a method that will update your  data.

Please have a look at the following link http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article29.aspx.

Feel free to get back to me if you need further assistance.